# Disabling something on startup

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

The following window always shows up at the startup. How to disable it.

[image]

**EDIT**: I have tried every possible imaginable way to install it or enable it(in turn windows features on/off) but it didn't work.That's why I am asking how to disable this annoyance.I am now really tired of this.

Comment: Download and install it?

Comment: . . . or disable the program that is trying to run at startup that is programmed using the .NET programming subsystem. Check the startup item in the start menu, or Use msconfig.exe as one method to selectivly disable a program running at startup.

Comment: what windows version are you running ? and doesn't microsoft provide .Net as part of the windows copy they gave you ?

Comment: One of the applications that is starting with Windows boot needs .Net 3.5. If you are not sure which program is doing this, try disabling one by one. @niceman I'm pretty sure Windows 8 doesn't come with .Net 3.5. Instead, it comes with 4.5/4 (I think)